# cxf webservice client generation issue

Tags: java, apache, web-services, client, cxf

I'm consuming a web service using apache cxf... (2.4.2)

The below is the xml section I need to generate as per the sample by vendor.

```
<erep:TransactionStatusCol>
                    <erep1:TransStatusEnum>All</erep1:TransStatusEnum>
                </erep:TransactionStatusCol>
```

the below is the code.

```
ArrayOfTransStatusEnum arrayOfTranStatuseum = new ArrayOfTransStatusEnum();
        arrayOfTranStatuseum.getTransStatusEnum().add(TransStatusEnum.ALL);
        JAXBElement<ArrayOfTransStatusEnum> tranStatusJaxB = objReports.createArrayOfTransStatusEnum(arrayOfTranStatuseum ) ;
        criteria.setTransactionStatusCol(tranStatusJaxB);
```

but actually the xml is generated as below by cxf...

```
 <ns2:ArrayOfTransStatusEnum>
          <ns2:TransStatusEnum>All</ns2:TransStatusEnum>
   </ns2:ArrayOfTransStatusEnum>
```

Trying to understand what am I missing here ...

Comment: Please explain  bit more........

Comment: CXF generated a soap xml using the type of the field , not the name of the field.

Comment: I am setting the a sepcfici field called "transaction statusses" to criteria. 

the code is below.. 

JAXBElement<ArrayOfTransStatusEnum> arrayOfStatuses = objFactor.createArrayOfTransStatusEnum();
 criteria.setTransactionStatusCol(arrayOfStatuses);
 
 so I expect CXF to generate the request xml as below.. 
 
 <criteria>
 <TransactionStatusCol>
   ...statuses...
 </TransactionStatusCol>
 </ctiteria>
 
 
 Instead it created  using the type of the field that was set. 
 
 <criteria>
 <ArrayOfTransStatusEnum>
 .. statuses
 </ArrayOfTransStatusEnum>
 </criteria>